# <Stripe/Stripe.h> file not found ?? Flutter Stripe Payment iOS Error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe in my flutter project its working fine on Android Device but not working on iOS Device it shows Error Lexical or Preprocessor error <Stripe/Stripe.h> file not found error in XCode.
if any one have fixed this please guide thanks in Advance.

Comment: Related issue on the Tipsi repo (not Flutter but may be helpful since it's an Xcode import error): https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/230

Comment: I have already tried all suggestion in above link but un able to fix my Issue